# Django returns blank QuerySet despite names matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model `Employee`, where one of the fields is `manager`, which is a `ForeignKey` to another model called `Manager`. 
I am checking whether a manager value I'm passing through the previous page matches with an object of `Employee` that has the same manager, and I want to get only those objects where the manager matches. However, despite me having employees that have different managers each, I try filtering using `Employee.objects.get(manager=manager)` or `Employee.objects.filter(manager=manager)`, and neither returns anything.
 `filter` returns a blank queryset and `get` says `Employee matching query does not exist.` despite it clearly matching. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**CODE**

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Attendance
from .models import Employee, Manager
from datetime import datetime



employee_list = ["John", "Jane", "Jacob", "Mark", "Jingleheimer", "Rob", "Schmidt"]

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@login_required
def attendance(request):
    manager_list = Manager.objects.all()
    now = timezone.now().date
    status = 0
    for manager in manager_list:
        if ' ' in manager.name:
            manager.select_name = manager.name.replace(' ', '_')
        else:
            pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        manager = request.POST.get('manager')
        print(manager)
        return redirect('mark_attendance', manager=manager)
    return render(request, 'attendance.html', {
        "date": now,
        "status": status,
        "manager_list": manager_list,
    })

@login_required
def mark_attendance(request, manager):
    print(manager) ##prints out the Manager object right
    employee_list = Employee.objects.get(manager=manager)
    print(employee_list)
    if request.method == "POST":
        for employee in employee_list:
            print(employee.pk)
            decision = request.POST.get(f'decision_{employee.pk}')
            print(decision)
            status = Attendance(employee=employee, date=datetime.now(), status=decision)
            status.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mark_attendance')
    else:
        return render(request, 'mark_attendance.html', {
            "employee_list": employee_list,
        })
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
import math
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from datetime import timedelta

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Manager(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    employee_id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AssignTime(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default='2018-10-23')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, choices=(
        (False, "Absent"),
        (True, "Present"),
    ))

    def __str__(self):
        sname = Employee.objects.get(name=self.employee)
        return '{0}'.format(sname.name)

class AttendanceRange(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Exactly *what* does it print for `print(manager)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It prints `Manager object (CW01)` if you select the first option and `Manager object (CW02)` if you select the second. I have created 3 Employee objects, two which have the manager as `Manager object (CW01)` and one with the manager as `Manager object (CW02)`

Comment: You don't want to use .get() if have multiple objects that could return, it will give you error.  This makes me believe that the manager may not be assigned to the employees in the backend like you think.  Double check that.        Where in your code are you trying to do this?  Please post that code